# Problems in specifying password with curl in ssl

Tags: ssl, curl, certificate

I am trying to connect to one of the organisation. I am using the following curl command:

`curl --cert mycert.pfx --pass abcdef  -v https://<website-name>`

I have this certificate lying in the directory I am executing the command from, and whenever I do this, I simply get

`curl: (58) SSL: Incorrect password for the certificate "mycert.pfx" and its private key`

However, when I open mycert.pfx using this,

`keytool -list -keystore mycert.pfx -storepass abcdef -storetype PKCS12 -v`

it works completely fine without any problems. I also have the tool keystore explorer and I have tried opening the certificate using the above password, and there too it works completely fine. I have also tried mentioning the PW `mycert.pfx:abcdef` like this. But this didn't work either.

Can anyone give me any idea as to where I might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this part of the documentation of curl's `--cert` option helps: *If you want to use a file from the current directory, please precede it with "./" prefix, in order
              to avoid confusion with a nickname.*. In other words: try `curl --cert ./mycert.pfx ...`

Comment: @Steffen, I have tried doing this too, and it didn't work either. I get the same error of incorrect password. Am I missing something?